# mysql daemon install as a service on windows

Tags: service, windows-7, mysql

I just [downloaded](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=451432) mysql 64 bit as a zip package from their website, extract it to c:\mysql

and added `c:\mysql\bin` to my path.

I then open a command prompt as administrator and run:

```
mysqld -install
```

To install the mysql server as a service. I then go to windows services and start MySQL (also tried `sc start MySQL` from cmd), but I get the following error message:

[image]

Upon inspecting the properties of the service, it shows the path as `C:\Program Files\MySQL-5.6.17\bin\` instead of `C:\mysql\bin`. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the FULL PATH of your mysql server `exe`

Try this:

```
"C:\mysql\bin\mysqld" -install
```

It turns out that the service installation routine expects the `.exe` to be at the MySQL default installation directory of `C:\Program Files\MySQL-5.6.17\bin\`

Your installation with the straightforward `mysqld -install` could work, albeit only partially, because you had the correct path under Windows `PATH`

This is certainly a great inadequacy in the MySQL documentation, which does not address this issue at all.

Knowing you might have resolved your problem one way or another, I still thought to post this here as it might be of help to someone with time!

Cheers.

Comment: In that case, if possible, could you post the solution that worked for you? Except you'll want to mark this one as the answer, if it is in line with the solution that worked for you :). The reason its important is: It helps the person in quest for an answer, to see that "This issue was solved in this way or that". Right?